# How can I connect to a database on my filesystem using Java

Tags: java, database, sqlite

I need to connect to a database on my file system but I have noticed that JDBC is referring to a database in memory, any time I want to check the tables need to write a code to retrieve their data, currently I have a SQLite database. 
I used the following code but even when I enter a correct address it does not connect to my database.

```
    String sDriver = "org.sqlite.JDBC";
    String Database = "users/documents/DB.sqlite";
    String sJdbc = "jdbc:sqlite";
```

Answer (score 1):

Move your database (DB.sqlite) in your working directory. Then use this url to connect to it :

```
jdbc:sqlite:DB.sqlite
```

Using JDBC, it will be something like this :

```
String driver = "org.sqlite.JDBC";
Class.forName(driver);

String dbUrl = "jdbc:sqlite:DB.sqlite";
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl);
```

Comment: [As of 6 days ago](https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/issue/13/please-add-meta-inf-services-javasqldriver), you don't need to do `Class.forName`.

Comment: Not always. It depends on the environment (server, desktop application) from the run, even using Java 6.